# Prevent Microsoft Sync from running at Startup

Tags: windows-10, sync

Using x64 Windows 10 (build 17763.1098). Whenever the computer starts up, quickly load Task Manager and `Microsoft Sync Center` (Mobsync.exe) briefly runs before shutting down. Is there any way to stop this altogether?

All of the following are done and confirmed:

- `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CscService\Start` is 0x00000004
- `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CSC\Start` is 0x00000004
- The `Control Panel\Control Panel\Administrative Tools\Service\Offline Files` service is disabled, as expected
- `Local Group Policy (gpedit.msc) > Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Network\Offline Files\Allow or disallow use of the Offline Files feature` has been configured to "Disabled"
- The computer has been rebooted multiple times

According to a comment in [this link describing how to disable Offline Files](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/disable-sync-center-mobsync-exe-running-windows/), this may be a bug in Windows itself. That article and comment are from a year ago in May 2019, so it is possible the bug has not been addressed.

**Update**

I've taken the drastic step of renaming the `mobsync.exe` file in C:\Windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64 to `mobsync-orig.exe`. Naturally this "resolves" the issue, but it would be better if there were a more elegant solution.

Note: To rename these, you need to take ownership of the file from `TrustedInstaller` with Properties > Security > Advanced > Change. Then add `Full Rights` to the local Administrators group.

Answer (score 1):

More elegant way;

```
New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\mobsync.exe" | New-ItemProperty -Name Debugger -PropertyType String -Value "%windir%\System32\systray.exe" -Force
```

Modifying files will corrupt the windows integrity check and (especially anti cheat systems) don't like this.

Comment: What does that command do?

Comment: Used to attach a debugger to an executable, using systray.exe instead (Leftover from earlier windows?) and is often used as a dummy executable, it basically doesn't start up mobsync.exe to begin with.

You can use this for all kinds of windows executables (Think Compattellogger.exe etc)